# Is every splitting-simple group $G$ Hopfian?

Tags: group-theory, retraction, hopfian

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Then a homomorphism $r : G \to H$ is said to be a
*retraction* if  $r(x) = x$ for all elements $x\in H$. Then $H$ is called a *retract* of $G$.

A nontrivial group is said to be *splitting-simple* if it has no proper nontrivial
retracts. Clearly every simple group is splitting-simple. Also $\mathbb{Z}$ is a non-simple splitting-simple group.

It can be easily seen that every simple group is Hopfian (recall that a group $G$ is *Hopfian* if every epimorphism $f : G \to G$ is an automorphism).

**My question**: Is every splitting-simple group $G$ Hopfian? If not, what is the necessity for $G$ to be Hopfian?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to the first question is. No.

The Prüfer $p$-group is non-Hopfian group, but it has no proper nontrivial retracts,
since each of its subgroups is finite and any homomorphic image is a divisible group.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer.